# How to retrieve the status of users has same interest Mysql query issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am learning MYsql and php. Now stuck with this weird problem in mysql. I have two tables
`soc_users_interest` and `soc_status`. Please see the table structure below.

```
----------                -----------
soc_status                soc_users_interest
----------                ------------
status_ID                 soc_interest_id (Auto increment)
status                    userID
userID                    Interest
```

i am trying to list all status of users which has same interests of the user  (User who use the application). I made a query and it's not returning the right results. Here's the query i wrote which doesn't work.

```
 SELECT soc_status.statusID, soc_status.status FROM soc_status
WHERE soc_status.userID =

      (SELECT  
  soc_users_interest.userID as firstUser , 
  soc_users_interest.interest as firstUserInterest , 

  secondUser.userID as secondUser, 
  secondUser.interest as secondUserInterest 

 FROM soc_users_interest JOIN
  soc_users_interest secondUser 
     ON soc_users_interest.interest = soc_users_interest.interest) WHERE soc_users_interests.userID = "23445";

I am getting this error -> `[2016-07-09 20:53:26] [21000][1241] Operand should contain 1 column(s)`
```

How can i  list all status of users which has same interests of the user (User who use the application) ? Any solutions to this problem ?. Thanks for helping ;)

Comment: "It doesn't work" give us no useful information at all. If it were working properly, you wouldn't ask a question here. What is the expected output? What is the current output? Is there an error message?

Comment: I updated the question. @Jocelyn

Comment: Try `soc_status.userID in( )` instead of `soc_status.userID =`

Comment: same error  Operand should contain 1 column @starshine531

Comment: okay, so the reason that's happening is that there's 4 different fields you are selecting in the subquery.  It needs to be only one the way this query is currently structured.

Comment: i already know that. So how can i make it work with multiple columns sir ? :)

Comment: Looking at this more closely, you need to not have it be a subquery, but join on the `soc_status` table on userID

Comment: @starshine531 i need to join with what table ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you what you need.  Though I don't have your tables, so I have not tested it.

```
SELECT  
  soc_users_interest.userID as firstUser , 
  soc_users_interest.interest as firstUserInterest , 
  secondUser.userID as secondUser, 
  secondUser.interest as secondUserInterest ,
  soc_status.statusID, soc_status.status

 FROM soc_users_interest, soc_users_interest secondUser,soc_status
 WHERE  
 firstUser.interest = secondUser.interest
 AND soc_status.userID=secondUser.userID
 AND firstUser.userID = "23445";
```

Comment: check the updated question. I modified the query like u said with a join.

Comment: could you be more specific?  What didn't work? did you get an error message, or just different results than you wanted?

Comment: imgur.com/a/GCkAc @starshine531 . it's showing a different result

Comment: What did you want to get in your result? Perhaps I misunderstood what you wanted. Did you want only the status messages? If so, just remove the unwanted items from the select clause  Could you give a sample of what an ideal result would be?

Comment: i want the status of the users who has same interest of user a. @starshine531

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT soc2.userID, soc2.status, int.interest  FROM soc_status soc1
join soc_status soc2 on soc1.user_id=soc2.user_id and soc1.user_id="23445"
join soc_users_interest int on soc1.user_id=int.user_id
```

Comment: [2016-07-10 12:25:39] [42S22][1054] Unknown column

Comment: what is this? Is this the error you are getting? Try to be more clear in your questions/comments?

Answer (score 0):

Just a question. Why do you need 2 tables. Combined this data into one. If you feel that you cannot have 1 table, use a table JOIN with the correct number of columns WHERE tbl1.Userid = tbl2.Userid